# AJAX ignoring .Net Session Variables

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, session

I have an MVC site that handles the login process for a few applications. When a user logs in, a session variable gets created within the Login app's memory.

The login App has a controller action that can be called that checks that session variable (in the controller) and if it exists returns a view to display a logout button. If it does not exist, it returns a view with the login button.

On another site, we can load this controller action within an iFrame and the button displays just like it's supposed to.

Now we want some additional functionality for the logout button, including a dropdown list for updating settings, username, password, etc. The iFrame solution no longer works because the menu cannot overflow the iFrame container. So we figured we'd just load the content via AJAX. But AJAX always gets back the login button, whether the user is logged in or not.

Login Controller:

```
    public ActionResult LoginButton()
    {
        if (Session["User"] == null)
            return View("LoginButton");
        else
            return View("LogoutButton");
    }
```

LoginButton View:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<span style="">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/Welcome" class="btn btn-primary" target="_top">Login</a>
</span>
```

LogoutButton View:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<span style="">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/" class="btn btn-primary" target="_top">Log Out</a>
</span>
```

All of that is on siteA.com.

On siteB.com...

iFrame that loads the log out button when a user is logged in:

```
<iframe style="border:none; width:150px; height:50px;" scrolling="no" src="http://siteA.com/logInButton"></iframe>
```

AJAX that loads login button regardless of user status.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#LogInOutBtn').load("http://siteA.com/logInButton"); 
    });
</script>                               
<div id=LogInOutBtn ></div>
```

I've also tried $.get but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post how you set your session. As I can see only code that include just to check session object is null or not.

Please update further code so that we can help you in proper manner

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a CORS issue. The session cookie was not passed cross-domain because .load() and $.get() don't set withCredentials (Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) to true.